# Flutter on M1 MBP Unable to run on ios simulator

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

Here is the output after running `doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.3)
    ! CocoaPods 1.5.2 out of date (1.10.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I have tried to update CocoaPods, but I still keep getting the above error when I run doctor.

```
(base) mbp % sudo gem install cocoapods
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.11.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

When running `flutter run`:

```
(base) mbp % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.9.0 or greater not installed.
Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code
  that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.
```

Comment: i also have m1 and i tried install brew and use brew to install cocoapods

Comment: Does it work for you? I've tried a bunch of stackoverflow solutions as well as github issues

Comment: yes its does at first am using sudo but triedrun flutter doctor -v same thing still cocoapods